# Fish-Shell Will Not Save my Aliases

Tags: shell, alias, fish

I do not know why, but after making a whole bunch of fish aliases.  I'm assuming I have neglected one simple step after assigning them all but I cannot seem find the solution myself.

Can anyone lend me a hand?

Thank you very much!

~Ev

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It basically boiled down to:

1. Open `~/.config/fish/config.fish` in your favorite editor.  If it's not already there, it'll make it for you.  (Don't `su` it though.)
2. Add all the aliases you want.  It'll save them and always load then because this is apparently Fish's version of bashrc.
3. Save it, baby!
4. Enjoy.

Comment: I prefer this method so that I can easily edit my aliases in a single file.

Answer (score 32):

A fish alias is actually implemented as a function. To save a function, you need `funcsave`. So this is the sequence

```
alias foo=bar
funcsave foo
```

That creates ~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish which will then be available in any fish session.

The `alias` command also works without the `=`:

```
alias foo "bar baz qux"
```

Comment: @MrNycticorax, the alias syntax without the = [goes way back in fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/commands.html#alias)